# React-Native application: right and left are swapped

Tags: ios, react-native, swap, right-to-left

On web, the order is just fine, but on mobile everything is swapped: the order of the components, left margins are right margins etc.
I did not change anything on purpose. From one build to another, the order simply changed.

I attached a screenshot from one of their templates which shows the same behavior (so the problem is not restricted to a single project):
[screenshot from react-native template ios application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjiJS.jpg)

Thank you!

**Update:**

**code:** https://github.com/expo/examples/blob/master/with-tab-navigation/App.js

**image:** [screenshot from mobile phone ios](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrrsA.jpg)

I also checked with another phone and it shows the proper order. Could it be related to some language or region?

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox works the same way in React Native as it does in CSS on the web, with a few exceptions. The defaults are different, with flexDirection defaulting to column instead of row, alignContent defaulting to flex-start instead of stretch, flexShrink defaulting to 0 instead of 1, the flex parameter only supporting a single number.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/flexbox

Comment: I know they should be the same. This is why I don't understand why it's showing differently. The screenshot has the tabs in a different order than the web version. For some reason, on mobile stuff is mirrored

Comment: @MrRobot flexDirection  is different in RN and react js

Comment: my problem is not related to css code. the provided template from expo shows the tabs in order: tab one and tab two. my problem is that they are now swapped. tab two is first, then tab one. without changing anything to the template

Comment: @MrRobot can you please show yours code ?

Comment: https://github.com/expo/examples/blob/master/with-tab-navigation/App.js

Comment: code that you gived looks like different that screenshot in question and works good @MrRobot

Comment: yes, because the screenshot from the question is with expo template and i could not find it on github to send you the repo so I chose a similar one. I built the app with the code I provided first and the error is still the same. the order is wrong. so what I am trying to say is that this is not project related. for some reason, left is swapped with right globally

Comment: can you show code that reproduce swaping bug on phone ? @MrRobot

Comment: I updated the question. the image is for the above sent code. On my phone it is swapped, on another is shown in the proper order. could it be language related or sth?

Comment: I reinstalled the expo go app on my mobile and it works now... I have no idea why it was reversed. maybe a glitch
Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled my Expo Go application from mobile and reinstalled it from App Store. Works now